# javascript changes type in for/in loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, types

This code:

```js
function sum(a) {
  let total = 0;
  for (let i in a) {
    if (typeof i !== 'number') {
      // throw new TypeError('sum(): elements must be numbers');
      console.log(i,typeof i);
    }
    total += i;
  }
  return total;
}

let ar = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(typeof ar[0]);
sum(ar);
```

outputs:

```
number
string
string
string
```

Why does the loop changes type? (as opposed to `for/of` loop, where the type is preserved)

Comment: Properties of objects are always string (or symbol), even when you get them from an array object. Conclusion: don't use `for..in` on arrays. You probably wanted to use `for..of`, as you seem to want to sum the array *values*, not the array *indexes*.

Comment: Also `const sum = ar.reduce((a,b) => a+b)`